# Forms Login changes from VS 2005 to VS 2013, Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am following Scott Mitchell's instructions for creating the forms for Forms login pages.

Here is the link:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb

He wrote these for VS 2005, and I am using VS 2013.

The problem is, the frame for the sub pages on the Site.Master do not line up.

[image: How it looks on my page]

[image: How it looks in Scott's tutorial]

I copied his code for all pages exactly (except I moved the  "content" and I added the line:...

```
<div id="nothing">
    Here for a moment

</div>
<p></p>
```

...because I was looking to see if I could manipulate and massage the code to get it to work. 
The key thing is that I cannot put the "MainContent" beside the "TODO" frame. I tried to grab the "MainContent" and place it next to the "TODO" frame, and it put it below it.

When I look at the properties for either of the `<div>`s, "content" and "navigation", neither has the property, "position".

Comment: It looks like you're missing the CSS Styles.   If you look at the markup for the master page in the tutorial, you'll see `<link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in the `<head>` section.  Do you have that line, and you do you have the "Styles.css" file?

Comment: Yes, exactly as he wrote it.

Comment: Do you also have the "Styles.css" file?  Having the link in the markup won't do you any good if you don't have the file as well.

Comment: I added after the entry from Tim, below. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshots, it looks like no CSS is being applied, most likely because the referenced "Styles.css" file is not available in your project.

From the tutorial's posted code:

```
<link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If you look at the markup on the master page, for example:

```
<div id="header">
  <span class="title">User Account Tutorials</span>
```

You'll see that there's a `<div>` (header), and it contains a `<span>` with a class of "title".  In the Styles.css (which can be downloaded along with the rest of the code), you'll note the following:

```
#header {
    border-top: 3px solid #B51032;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #B51032;
    height: 3em;
}
#header .title {
    font: 190% Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
    margin-left: .8em;
}
```

Among other things.  "#header" refers to the element that has an id of "header", and #header .title refers (in this case) to the `<span>` with a class of "title" under the header.

The CSS file allows the UI to be changed in any number of ways without affecting the actual markup - i.e., you can apply different styles to the same markup to get different looks.